# TR- VB.NET Clipboard Copy Richtxtbx CTRL+C

Tags: vb.net, copy, richtextbox, turkish

I'm doing a notepad style program.

```
    If e.Control = True And e.KeyCode = Keys.C Then
        MsgBox("Kopyalandı")
        My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(RichTextBox1.SelectedText)
        RichTextBox1.Focus()
    End If
```

As we make, type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy the selected word, but what I want in my MsgBox emits as

```
    If e.Control = True And e.KeyCode = Keys.C Then
        My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(RichTextBox1.SelectedText)
        RichTextBox1.Focus()
    End If
```

Can not copy the selected word (the program comes out of my google etc. we make <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to copy and paste the words I can not.) I wrote the code by which I try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> MsgBox exiting the program, even if you exit out of the selected word copies?

Answer (score 1):

`My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText` will copy to the clipboard so it can be pasted into external applications. You should use an event such as KeyDown to check for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. You can test it out with another key to make sure <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is not being intercepted by another control or form.

Comment: My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText harici uygulamalar içine yapıştırılan böylece panoya kopyalar. Sen Ctrl-C kontrol etmek için böyle KeyDown gibi bir olay kullanmanız gerekir. Ctrl-C, başka bir denetime veya formda tarafından yakalanan edilmediğinden emin olmak için başka bir anahtar ile bunu test edebilirsiniz.